# Strapi: can't save anything in admin

Tags: permissions, admin, strapi

I installed Strapi, apparently successfully, but anything I try to save gives me an error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

I have it installed on a centos 7 server.

I was even able to create a few content-types, but when I try to make relational fields I get this error.

I thought it would be something related to roles and permissions plugin. Tried to change permissions, but same error. Tried updating my profile, also error.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just figured it out.

Mod segurity was on. Had to turn it off.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).